# Translating Python 2 byte checksum calculator to Python 3

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, python-3.x, byte

I'm trying to translate this Python 2 code to Python 3.

```
def calculate_checksum(packet):
  total = 0
  for char in packet:
    total += struct.unpack('B', char)[0]
  return (256 - (total % 256)) & 0xff
```

In Python 3 it causes a TypeError:

```
    total += struct.unpack('B', char)[0]
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'int'
```

I have been trying to research the changes in strings and bytes but it is a bit overwhelming.

Comment: I would try `bytes(char)` instead. but a [mcve] would be the best way to make sure.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: the whole `struct` call is *redundant*. All it does is turn a single character (unsigned char) to their integer equivalent for that byte. It's the `ord()` function, basically. Except in Python 3, iteration over `bytes` already gives you just the integers.

Comment: @MartijnPieters of course! sometimes I forget to look at the bigger picture

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code basically translates individual characters in a bytestring to their integer equivalent; the character `\x42` becomes 0x42 (or decimal 66), for example:

```
>>> # Python 2
...
>>> struct.unpack('B', '\x42')[0]
66
```

As an aside, you could do the same more simply with the [`ord()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#ord):

```
>>> ord('\x42')
66
```

In Python 3, you **already** get integers when you iterate over a `bytes` object, which is why you get your error:

```
>>> # Python 3
...
>>> b'\x42'[0]
66
```

The whole `struct.unpack()` call can simply be dropped:

```
for char in packet:
    total += char
```

or simply use `sum()` to calculate the total in one step:

```
total = sum(packet)
```

making the complete version:

```
def calculate_checksum_ord(packet):
    total = sum(ord(c) for c in packet)
    return (256 - (total % 256)) & 0xff
```

Note that the Python 2 code could also use `sum()`, with the `ord()` function rather than use `struct`: `total = sum(ord(c) for c in packed)`.